# Maclaurin series to prove $\sin(x)>\ln(1+x)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I need to use Maclaurin series in order to show that for every $x\in(0,1)$,
$$\sin(x)>\ln(1+x).$$
I don't know from where to start, I think I should define $$f(x)=\sin(x)-\ln(1+x)$$
and then to prove that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in(0, 1)$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly and around zero:

$$\sin x-\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}+\mathcal O(x^7)-\left(x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3-\mathcal O(x^4)\right)=$$

$$=\frac12x^2+\frac16x^3+\mathcal O(x^4)\ge0\;,\;\;|x|<1$$

since the radius of convergence for the logarithm's series about zero is $\;1\;$ , and thus the above is true for $\;x\in(0,1)\;$